# Connect rails to Sql Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, activerecord

I am trying to connect Rails to Sql Server so I need to use an Sql Server adaptor. I installed it by downloading the adaptor locally from github.com/Desarrollo-CeSPI/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git. After that I did: `gem build activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.gemspec` in the directory where I had the spec file, followed by `gem install <name of gem that was just built>`.
After that, I added this line in the gemfile:
`gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter',  :path  => 'downloads/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-master\activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-master'` , then I ran a `bundle install` from the project root.

The error is:

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord": In
>   Gemfile: rails <=4.1.6> x86-mingw32 depends on    activerecord <=4.1.6>
>   x86-mingw32
>
> activerecord-sqlserver-adapter <>=0> x86-mingw32 depends on
>   activerecord <4.0.0>

What is strange is `rails -v` doesn't return the rails version although I just installed it.
Instead it throws:

```
Could not find gem 'tzinfo-data <>=0> x86-mingw32 in the gems available on this machine
Run bundle install to install missing gems
```

I should specify we are compulsed to use proxies at work

Every few month I keep checking to see if the Sql Server connection is improved/easier to perform with Rails without adaptors and such, because I want to use Sql Server instead of PostgreSQL. No luck so far. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: have you tried the `mysql2` gem? (on a sidenote: ruby is not really windows compatible)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the gem that you are using only supports until rails 4.0.0 (the gemspec forces to be this version).

You might try to use that rails version to see what's going on.

To do so, in your `Gemfile.rb` you can try this:

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', git: 'https://github.com/Desarrollo-CeSPI/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git'

and then run

```
bundle update rails # to force using the rails version specified in the gemfile
```

and then run

```
bundle install
```

**BUT**

- The gem that you are using has not been updated since 22nd August 2013, so I would not expect it work.
- The gem that you are using is a fork of the original project located at https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter

If you don't have anything to do with Desarrollo-CeSPI, then you should use the official gem to avoid some problems, for instance that the gem is not maintained anymore.